# Painfully slow make with IDEA 12.0

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I love the new incremental Java compile in IDEA 12.0 but there seems to be a price to pay.  Making now takes about twice as long as in 11.x, most of the time appearing to be spent

> Executing DEX

(according to the status bar).

I can take a 12.0 project, revert to 11.x and making is back to "normal speed" (approx 4 minutes vs 30 seconds).

I don't get this.  AFAIK, IDEA (or Eclipse or any other IDE) is just shelling out to dx.jar to compile the Dalvik executable.  If there was a problem with the ADT, it would affect 11.x equally.

OS is Win 7 Ultimate.  3.2GHz quad core with 16GB but I suspect that the issue is not related to OS or PC since 11.x is OK.

Any ideas?  I'll log a bug with Jetbrains but wanted to see if anyone has more concrete info or workarounds?  There's nothing so far on the Jetbrains bug tracker or fora that I can find.

Comment: It may be worth filing a bug on their bug tracker for sure.  Do you know if you're running anything else in the background?  If you have a SSD, that will improve build times just by virtue of I/O operations.

Comment: @Makoto.  Thanks for the response.  It's a good old fashioned steam driven PC (but a bit of a monster, quad core, 16GB etc... ;).  Nothing of significance running in the background and CPU is pegged at <1% when not making.

Comment: Did you file a bug already? Does [this setting](http://img189.imageshack.us/img189/3550/20121206235318.png) affect the compilation speed (try to disable it)?

Comment: I haven't filed a bug yet, sorry.  Just haven't been able to find the time.  I did disable the external build, with no effect, but the problem seems to be with DEXing, not compiling.

Comment: just out of curiosity are you running the x86 or x64 version of the executable for idea?

Comment: x64.  Haven't tried x86 but will tomorrow and get back.  I do know it's not intrinsic since I now use a second PC and the same project builds fine on that one.

Comment: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-101291

Comment: I have this problem too, but it only just started happening.  I has just installed Android Studio.. I wonder if it clobbered some ide level config somewhere.  My "Executing DEX" task basically never completes.

EDIT:  I found the problem for me.. will answer below

Answer (score 1):

I have had this issue a couple of times in the past and it's always been due to the inclusion of a global library that hangs during build.

On one occasion it was due to the Python libraries trying to execute when the Android project was built because I had a python file in my Android project and IntelliJ decided to add the Python runtime libs to my project dependencies.

More recently the same thing happened with Groovy when I had a gradle file in the Android project.

For me I simply removed these dependencies from the project and the problem resolved itself.

In my case I discovered this by force killing (kill -9) the java process that was running the make.  This caused intellij to dump the error to the Messages view in the IDE where I could see groovy trying to execute.

Comment: I had jUnit jar in the libraries section, which wasn't used. Removing it resolved the problem.